# Python script is stuck at FileHandler

Tags: java, python, weblogic, weblogic12c

the control is stuck at the below code, i am trying to create a weblogic server domain using the below

```
 import os
import sys
import wl as myWLST

from java.lang import System,Runtime,Process,String
from java.io import BufferedReader,InputStreamReader,File
from java.util.logging import FileHandler,Logger,SimpleFormatter

from com.oracle.cie.domain.script.jython import WLSTException
from com.oracle.cie.domain.script import ScriptException
from WeblogicConfigXmlParser import XmlParser

#=====================
# Program starts here
#=====================
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "in main"
    print len(sys.argv)
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
                print 'Insufficent arguments'
                System.exit(-1)
    else:
        try:
            print "inside try - JASON"
            print (os.getcwd())
            fileHandler = FileHandler("weblogic.log",1);
            print "inside try 2"
            fileHandler.setFormatter(SimpleFormatter());
```

it is stuck at line "`fileHandler = FileHandler("weblogic.log",1);`", Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using semicolons?

Comment: @Shreya it is prewritten code which i am using not sure why semicolons are in place

Comment: Hello, I have seen those semicolons many times in Jython scripts and I think they were used by developers with Java background and even though they are harmless, it is better to get rid of them. When it comes to automating a domain's provisioning nowadays there are better ways to do so as using Ansible + WLST and Python as you can see here https://github.com/textanalyticsman/ansible-soa or you can also use Weblogic Deploy Tooling https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-deploy-tooling

Comment: @rcastellcastell thanks for the suggestion, Can you please tell me what is making this script stuck at filehandler ?

Comment: You can take several thread dumps from your wlst process to find where the java code is stucked. Use jps to get your wlst process id and fire a thread dump with jstack.
Next, share the thread dump.

Comment: I think the idea proposed by @EmmanuelCollin is the way to go. My two cents here, perhaps you should use strace to see what is going on at that point. I think the option -f of strace could be useful here to see all the threads.

Comment: Have you checked whether the file weblogic.log is too big? Issues with privileges?